# How to change a class __str__ method or extract a value from a method?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have code that is working but I need to polish the output, but I dont know how. I have a class with **str** method

```
 def __str__(self):
    rep = self.name + ":\t" + super(BJ_Hand, self).__str__()  
    if self.total:
        rep += "(" + str(self.total) + ")"        
    return rep
```

Later in the code I have a dictionary of the player(rep) and his total.

```
def play(self):
    # deal initial 1 cards to everyone
    self.deck.deal(self.players, per_hand = 1)

    for player in self.players:
        print(player)
        self.gamewar[player]= player.total
        
    import operator    
    rwinner=sorted(self.gamewar.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True)
    

    print("Winner is ", str(rwinner[0][0]))
```

for example I get the winner as
**Winner is  mat:   Kd  (13)**

The above display is in the for of rep from **str** which helps with the usage of the code. However I would like the winner to be just the name instead of the **str** rep. How do I do that?

Thanks

Comment: You mean like `print("Winner is", rwinner[0][0].name)`?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming 'player' is the class:

Last line: `print("Winner is ", str(rwinner[0][0]))`

Convert to: `print("Winner is ", rwinner[0][0].name)`

Another approach:
You could use the `__repr__()` method as well as the `__str__()` you already used.

```
def __str__(self):
    return self.name 


def __repr__(self):
    rep = self.name + ":\t" + super(BJ_Hand, self).__str__()  
    if self.total:
        rep += "(" + str(self.total) + ")"        
    return rep
```